# Excel: Automatically increment miliseconds by 1 for cell values with same date & time

Tags: excel, timestamp

> e.g. 2001-10-10 09:40:00 -> 2001-10-10 09:40:00,001
>         2001-10-10 09:40:00 -> 2001-10-10 09:40:00,002 etc.

Right now I'm trying `IF (A1 = A2; A1 + TIME (0;0;0,001); A1)` but no success.

Would be great if I can get a scalable solution too. :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Format cells as yyyy-m-d h:mm:ss
Cell A1 = "12/12/2012  12:00:00 PM"
Place formula in A2 cell as "=A1+(1/24/60/60)"
```